# Select Statement Not Working ("mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid")

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\webareas\ie803\projectx\search.php on line 306

My php code is as follows:

```
    <?php

$car = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['car']);
$model = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['model']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['type']);
$colour = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['colour']);
$year = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['year']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['price']);


$con = mysql_connect("--","---","---");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('-----', $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make ='$car', Model ='$model', Type ='$type', Colour = '$colour', Year  = '$year', Price = '$price'";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);


{
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Make']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Model']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Type']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Colour']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Year']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Price']. "</td>";


        echo "<br/><br/><td>" . '<hr>' .  "</td>";


}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

line 306 is the while statement. I keep on getting errors after each change I make.

Comment: You are not performing the query.  You must call `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Voting to close. There're many examples everywhere on how to use the (obsolete) mysql extension.

Answer (score 2):

The select statement is just a string, you have to feed it through mysql_query to get the result set, it is typically done as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make ='$car', Model ='$model', Type ='$type', Colour = '$colour', Year  = '$year', Price = '$price'";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Comment: it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in E:\webareas\ie803\projectx\search.php on line 301

Comment: now it says Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\webareas\ie803\projectx\search.php on line 309

Comment: that shouldn't happen, can you update the above code to what you just tried?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have mysql_query(), try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make ='$car', Model ='$model', Type ='$type', Colour = '$colour', Year  = '$year', Price = '$price'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

**EDIT**
I put in the or die statement to help with debug, you can remove it at any time you wish. I personally find it makes it easier.

Comment: it says: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Model ='gt supersport', Type ='coupe', Colour = 'black', Year = '2000', Price ' at line 1

Comment: tomhallam is right, your sytax is wrong, changing the , for AND should have you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysql_query` before `mysql-fetch-aarray`. See this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for example of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your query is even being executed. I've never seen the syntax of `WHERE [column], [column], [column]` before.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make ='$car' AND Model ='$model' AND Type ='$type' AND Colour = '$colour' AND Year  = '$year' AND Price = '$price'
```

I've added some error checking so that you can see whatever mysql errors you get, if the syntax was correct.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make ='$car', Model ='$model', Type ='$type', Colour = '$colour', Year  = '$year', Price = '$price'";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);
if($result)    
{
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Make']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Model']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Type']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Colour']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Year']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['Price']. "</td>";


        echo "<br/><br/><td>" . '<hr>' .  "</td>";


}
else {
    die(mysql_error();
}
```